# Fancybox + дополнительная информация

Tags: jquery, fancybox, html

Добрый день.

Фотогалерея реализована с помощью fancybox. 
Но никак не могу понять, как в нее добавить свой кусок html.

Мне нужно, чтобы, помимо заголовка title, выводилось еще и подробное описание к каждой фотографии и при пролистывании фотки в fancybox была возможность передавать ID этой фотки, чтобы на заднем плане также менялось описание к конкретной фотографии и, соответственно, выделялась на заднем плане превьюшка для фотографии, которая в данный момент выбрана в fancybox.

Что-то уже и не знаю, куда копать. :( JS знаю так себе.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это целый ряд дополнительных задач.

1) поменять шаблон можно указав свойство tpl;
 2) в заголовок дописать своё можно устанавливая title;
 3) какие-либо действия при пролистывании можно выполнять по событию afterLoad. Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/) из официальной документации.

Comment: Большое спасибо. То, что доктор прописал.